# How to use absolute positioning in CSS to make the images in 2 rows of 3

Tags: html, css

I need to use absolute positioning to get these images, along with the text under them in rows of three. I am new to HTML/CSS and this requires me to use absolute or some other simple positioning method i cant use grid etc. I also need to make sure the news section stays where it is.

This is my HTML code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Walton Hall Museum of Odds &amp; Ends</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    <meta name="Tempany Johnson" content="zx813679"/>
     
  </head>
  <body>
      
       <nav class="navigation"> 
      <p>
          <a href="index.html" title="index.html">Museum of Odds &amp; Ends </a>
          <a href="placeholder.html" title="placeholder.html">Visit Us</a>
          <a href="placeholder.html" title="placeholder.html">Shop</a>
          <a href="placeholder.html" title="placeholder.html">Our History</a>
          </p>
      </nav>
      <div class="heading"><h1>Museum of Odds &amp; Ends</h1>
      <div class="subheading"><h2>Walton Hall, Milton Keynes</h2>
      
    <div id="museumimages">
      <a href="https://www.europeana.eu/en/item/440/item_UBMLSJFMKZCDOGRRMBW2UY5RDAL3V4IP">
        <img src="1.jpeg" alt="Budapest Chainbridge 1907"/>
            <p>Budapest Chainbridge 1907</p>
      </a>
      
      <a href="https://www.europeana.eu/en/item/369/_129030">
        <img src="3.jpeg" alt="Three red-figure attic vases 5th centruy AD"/>
            <p>Three red-figure attic vases</p>    
      </a>
     
      <a href="https://www.europeana.eu/en/item/325/MG061">
        <img src="4.jpeg" alt="Bronze Enamel Ring Pin Early Medieval"/>
            <p>Bronze Enamel Ring Pin</p>    
      </a>   
      
      <a href="https://www.europeana.eu/en/item/9200271/BibliographicResource_3000058904600">
        <img src="7.jpeg" alt="Glass-plate Slide by Erica Wagner"/>
            <p>Glass-plate Slide</p> 
      </a> 
     
      <a href="https://www.europeana.eu/en/item/2058611/_kimbl_3cd913c5_b586_4dd7_813b_14708e134f5e">
        <img src="10.jpeg" alt="Oilpainting of Ettingen Village by Alois Kron"/>
            <p>Oilpainting of Ettingen Village</p>  
      </a>
    
      <a href="https://www.europeana.eu/en/item/2058611/_kimbl_8a7b633f_8dfa_4bdb_ab43_5c7acb1d06ca">
        <img src="11.jpeg" alt="Painting by Soja Feldmaier"/>
            <p>Painting by Soja Feldmaier</p>    
      </a>
          </div>
      
    <article id=news>
      <h2>News</h2>
      <article>
        <h2>News Entry Title</h2>
          <h3>News Entry Date</h3>
          <p>News Entry Text</p>
      </article>  
      <article>
        <h2>News Entry Title</h2>
          <h3>News Entry Date</h3>
          <p>News Entry Text</p>
      </article>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS file

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333333;
    width: 1024px
}

.navigation {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #fefefe;
    width: 1024px;
    font-size: 120%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff0000; 
}

img {
    width:200px;
    height:100px; 
}

#news {

 position: absolute; right: 25px; top: 220px;

 text-align: left;

 font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

 font-size: 12px;

}

#museumimages {

 position: absolute; left: 24px; top: 200px;

}
```

Comment: "I am new to HTML/CSS and this requires me to use absolute or some other simple positioning method i cant use grid etc" You will need to learn them eventually. Why not start now?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest technique to have a grid-like display is using `display: inline-block`.

You can adapt it your case, but the fundamentals are here: https://jsfiddle.net/y6hgnv4f/1/